# Database growth by month

Tags: sql-server

I want a Query which can give output database name, database size and database  growth percentage and MB by month. Please help.thanks

Comment: See this post - https://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sql-server-track-database-size-growth-trend/

Comment: You might get some info out of backup sets: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/trending-database-growth-from-backups/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not already tracking this information you cannot pull this up for historical dates.  You will need to start saving this information in your database each month and then in the future you will be able to refer to it.  At the very least you should store the name and size of the database for what you want but I would suggest exploring the table to see what other useful bits you may want to preserve.

```
select * from sys.databases
```

If you have multiple data files (particularly if they are stored on different volumes) then you may also be interested in storing information from:

```
select * from sys.master_files
```